# XRDP exits emediately after login

Tags: xubuntu, lightdm, xrdp, vps

I installed xrdp on vps based on [this instruction](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-install-xrdp-on-ubuntu-20-04/)
XRDP exits emediately after loging in from windows 10.

UBUNTU 20.04

display-manager: lightdm

desktop: xubuntu-desktop

**xrdp-sesman.log:**

```
[20210225-20:43:21] [INFO ] A connection received from ::ffff:127.0.0.1 port 58494
[20210225-20:43:21] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username root, ip ::ffff:37.202.123.47:19329 - socket: 12
[20210225-20:43:21] [INFO ] starting Xorg session...
[20210225-20:43:21] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET6 :: port 5910)
[20210225-20:43:21] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET6 :: port 6010)
[20210225-20:43:21] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET6 :: port 6210)
[20210225-20:43:21] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:127.0.0.1 port 3350)
[20210225-20:43:21] [INFO ] calling auth_start_session from pid 3983
[20210225-20:43:21] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:127.0.0.1 port 3350)
[20210225-20:43:21] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET6 ::ffff:127.0.0.1 port 3350)
[20210225-20:43:21] [INFO ] /usr/lib/xorg/Xorg :10 -auth .Xauthority -config xrdp/xorg.conf -noreset -nolisten tcp -logfile .xorgxrdp.%s.log
[20210225-20:43:22] [CORE ] waiting for window manager (pid 3987) to exit
[20210225-20:43:22] [CORE ] window manager (pid 3987) did exit, cleaning up session
[20210225-20:43:22] [INFO ] calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 3983
[20210225-20:43:22] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets:
[20210225-20:43:22] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdp_chansrv_audio_out_socket_10
[20210225-20:43:22] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdp_chansrv_audio_in_socket_10
[20210225-20:43:22] [DEBUG] cleanup_sockets: deleting /run/xrdp/sockdir/xrdpapi_10
[20210225-20:43:22] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username root, display :10.0, session_pid 3983, ip ::ffff:37.202.123.47:19329 - socket: 12
```

**xsession-errors log:**

```
Xsession: X session started for root at Thu 25 Feb 2021 08:43:22 PM CET
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/0/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:10.0
localuser:root being added to access control list
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting USER=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANGUAGE=en_US:
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_TYPE=x11
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting HOME=/root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XRDP_PULSE_SINK_SOCKET=xrdp_chansrv_audio_out_socket_10
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XRDP_PULSE_SOURCE_SOCKET=xrdp_chansrv_audio_in_socket_10
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DBUS_SESSION_BUS_ADDRESS=unix:path=/run/user/0/bus
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PULSE_SCRIPT=/etc/xrdp/pulse/default.pa
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting IM_CONFIG_PHASE=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LOGNAME=root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_SESSION_CLASS=user
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PATH=/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin:/snap/bin
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XRDP_SOCKET_PATH=/run/xrdp/sockdir
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting DISPLAY=:10.0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting LANG=en_US.UTF-8
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting UID=0
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting SHELL=/bin/bash
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting QT_ACCESSIBILITY=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XRDP_SESSION=1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting GPG_AGENT_INFO=/run/user/0/gnupg/S.gpg-agent:0:1
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting PWD=/root
dbus-update-activation-environment: setting XDG_DATA_DIRS=/usr/share/gnome:/usr/local/share:/usr/share:/var/lib/snapd/desktop
```

I searched this problem, but not found any good help.

Comment: Someone has written a [script](http://c-nergy.be/blog/?p=15978) to make `xrdp` work with Ubuntu's default gnome desktop. If you want to do this, you may have to uninstall xubuntu-desktop and undo the changes you made to use xrdp with xfce.